# Reading vector whose elements are separated by "ENTER"

Tags: r, csv, vector

I have a csv file of a vector like below (only head)

```
[1] "peoria ave               [2] "wood dr                [3] "blahblah
     nste                          nphoenix"                   aaaaa"  
     npeoria"
```

When I read it using read.csv() i get a vector(or data frame, whatever) like below

```
[1] "peoria ave\nste \npeoria"    [2]   "wood dr\nphoenix"     [3]"blahblah\aaaaa"
```

So you see "ENTER" is getting replace by '\'. I do not want this. A 'space' or a 'comma' or 'underscore' would be fine. This 'backslash' is not actually there.

How do I resolve this. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: `gsub("\\n","",yourvector)`

Comment: If I somehow able to know how to write "ENTER key" in R. I might be able to use gsub to remove those.

Comment: @Roland awesome. Thank you. You may want to convert it into an answer.

Comment: I think it would be useful to read `?regexp`.

Comment: Also read `?Quotes` and observe that `\n` is a newline. `